# symfony docker postgres database creation problem

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, symfony

when I try to create the database with the command:

symfony console doctrine:database:create

i get this error :

SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  could not open file "global/pg_filenode.map": Permission denied

I'm trying to create a database in docker container postgres

Thanks for your help

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: It will be hard to answer your question without more details. Please provide your Dockerfile and docker-compose (if you're using compose), at least.

Answer (score 0):

it's good, I found !

I had a docker volume with same name.

After erasing the old volume, it worked !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).